# why она всегда думает о сыне instead of она всегда думает о её сыне?

Tags: грамматика

`why она всегда думает о сыне instead of она всегда думает о её сыне?`

Is this reduction common? must i occult the pronoun whenever the suject and also whose posses is close to the object of possesion in the setence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use a possessive pronoun before the noun "son",but it won't be **её** which is incorrect.You should say **своего** with any personal pronoun,if the boy is really her son.

> Она всегда думает о своём сыне.or Она всегда думает о сыне.

Both are correct. We can leave out the possessive pronoun and it will be clear that she is thinking about her own son.

Comment: Thank you, specially by the correction :) just to confirm in: родители всегда думают о нас, the parents here probably refers to the parents of the suject right?

Comment: "Родители" is the subject.

Comment: parents would be our parents, yep. And yep, "родители" is the subject.

Comment: sorry i asked wrong, do the parents refers to the speaker and those included in indirect object?

Comment: It's a general statement, I believe. Our parents think of us.Any parents always think of their children.

Comment: To try and clarify the matter for you a bit more. My English teacher used to call English a "very possessive language", which was to attract the students' attention to the obligatory nature of possessive pronouns in English. "I did MY homework". "He took off HIS hat". None of the above require a possessive pronoun in Russian which always implies that one is unlikely to take someone else's hat off or do someone else's homework. On the contrary, it is the directionality of action to someone else (someone else's possession) than has to be explicitly mentioned. "Она думает о сыне своей подруги".

Comment: Please note that though adding a possessive pronoun is not a mistake, it is still considered as a bad style.